# No `dell-linux-assistant` program upgrade

Tags: 20.04, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dell

using Dell G3 15 3500 with Ubuntu 20.04.1,
impossible to upgrade `dell-linux-assistant`

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
dell-linux-assistant/bionic 2.2.0545 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.0544]
dell-linux-assistant/now 2.2.0544 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.2.0545]
```

I think this pb come from my actual `20.04.1` come from an upgrade of `18.04`!

Please note too impossible to get this upgrade: `20.04.2`

According to @NOrbert's request

```
jrd_10@my-pc:~$ sudo apt-cache policy dell-linux-assistant
dell-linux-assistant:
   Installed: 2.2.0544
   Candidate: 2.2.0545
   Version table:
        2.2.0545 500
            500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
*** 2.2.0544 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy dell-linux-assistant` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1341276/edit).

Comment: Thank you for your request. I have added it.

Comment: I think that answer below solves your issue. If not please clarify the Ubuntu version. Is it bionic (18.04) or focal (20.04)?

Comment: Hi, thank again for your feedback.
On my Dell, it is the initial distro: 20.04.1! (Unable to update to .2)

I have the pb again

Comment: `jrd_10@my-pc:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
libxnvctrl0/focal-security 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
libxnvctrl0/focal-updates,now 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1]
libxnvctrl0/focal 440.64-0ubuntu1 amd64
...`
I understand as I have the last 20.04 version, these repositories have not been updated!

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy linux-libc-dev` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1341276/edit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a new ppa from [“The Somerville-dla team”](https://launchpad.net/%7Esomerville-dla-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for the *focal* variant.

in the terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:somerville-dla-team/ppa`

And deactivated the older ppa somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic main through software & updates (GUI).

after that in the terminal :

`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

which results in my case:

```
Er moeten 397 kB aan archieven opgehaald worden.
Na deze bewerking zal er 1.024 B extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Wilt u doorgaan? [J/n] j
Ophalen:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dell-linux-assistant amd64 2.2.0548 [397 kB]
397 kB opgehaald in 0s (3.064 kB/s)          
(Database wordt ingelezen ... 197398 bestanden en mappen momenteel geïnstalleerd
.)
Uitpakken van .../dell-linux-assistant_2.2.0548_amd64.deb wordt voorbereid...
Bezig met uitpakken van dell-linux-assistant (2.2.0548) over (2.2.0544) ...
Instellen van dell-linux-assistant (2.2.0548) ...
```

I had to restart the laptop (Dell XPS-13-9310) to get dell assistant running after this.

Comment: I thank you, it seems ok
`jrd_10@my-pc:~$ sudo apt-cache policy dell-linux-assistant
dell-linux-assistant:
  Installed: 2.2.0548
  Candidate: 2.2.0548
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.0548 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
jrd_10@my-pc:~$ 
`

Comment: `jrd_10@my-pc:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done`

Comment: Please, note it is the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (fossa-shireen X44), unable to upgrade to 20.04.2

Comment: didn't work on 22.04.3 LTS