# Installing Ubuntu 22.04 on a Windows Dell XPS 9310 - any OEM/Dell packages? Dell Linux Assistant?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, dell, xps

The Dell XPS 13 9310 is impossible to get with Ubuntu, so I bought a Windows version and installed Ubuntu. Seems to work well this far.

There are certain pages that mention drivers and specific applications:

- https://nrogap.medium.com/dell-repository-for-install-additional-drivers-on-ubuntu-4cf061640180
- [No `dell-linux-assistant` program upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341276/no-dell-linux-assistant-program-upgrade)

which seem to point at this http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/ which has entries for jammy:

- [DIR] jammy-dell-jellyfish-tentacool/ 2022-03-24 08:19    -
- [DIR] jammy-jiayi/    2022-04-22 12:53    -
- [DIR] jammy-somerville-tentacool/ 2022-04-30 00:28    -
- [DIR] jammy-somerville/   2022-04-27 06:41    -
- [DIR] jammy-stella/   2022-04-08 03:00    -
- [DIR] jammy-sutton/   2022-04-08 03:00    -
- [DIR] jammy/  2022-04-30 00:28

Could somebody explain the significance of these and how they could help run the XPS 9310 better on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Comment: Hello. My guess is that Dell OEM repositories for 22.04 LTS are still work in progress. As shown [here](https://people.ubuntu.com/~fourdollars/oem-meta-packages/), codename for your laptop model is `somerville-bulbasaur`. AFAIK still no repos exist for Jammy.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @becko, no - I didn't. I'll post here if I do. Thanks for asking!

Comment: If you haven't yet, be sure to `sudo apt install oem-somerville-bulbasaur-meta` for XPS 9310 support.