# Why do I get "AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'" during restart after upgrading my Dell system from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, python, 22.04, dell

After upgrading my Dell system from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I get the following warning message when I restart my system:

[image: Warning message at restart of the system]

Here is the above message as text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 715, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/dbus_backend.py", line 375, in deal_message
    QueueMessageClient(self.config, self.scheduler).LogLogMetricEvent("FRONTEND", "Dell Linux Assistant closes")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/telemetry_common.py", line 300, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/queue_message_client.py", line 107, in LogLogMetricEvent
    return self.triggerSend(filePath, header, Schedule)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DellLinuxAssistant/telemetry/queue_message_client.py", line 51, in triggerSend
    job = self.scheduler.add_interval_job(MessageHelper(self.configure).SendEvent, minutes=1, start_date=datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=1), args=[filePath, header], max_runs=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ApschedulerStandalone/scheduler.py", line 347, in add_interval_job
    return self.add_job(trigger, func, args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ApschedulerStandalone/scheduler.py", line 285, in add_job
    if not self.running:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ApschedulerStandalone/scheduler.py", line 148, in running
    thread_alive = self._thread and self._thread.isAlive()
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
```

I don't know what it means or if I should do something to correct an error, but I would like to stop seeing that message.

Comment: Seems something is crushing. The traceback show where did happen. You have to provide much more info, maybe a screenshot. Please make sure you have your system up-to-date. Start by running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` on a terminal. A good advice is not to rush to upgrade to last versions..

Comment: Without the exact error message it's very hard for us to say (*error details are usually multiple lines*) and your question contains no actual error message (*any details in the title should also exist in the question itself as titles may not be readable on some devices*).  Problems can occur often because changes were made to default python tools; you didn't make any did you?  (now or back whilst using 20.04/focal?)

Comment: it happens at restart of the system and i get the following message

Comment: I found this solution on this link https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Now-on-22-04-Stuck-with-a-Warning-Linux-Dell-Assistant-pop-up/m-p/8293559

Answer (score 2):

This question is addressed on Super User: [Why am I seeing these traceback and Python related warnings after I installed Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/q/1691904/226738)

You should be able to add the repository for [Somerville-dla](https://launchpad.net/%7Esomerville-dla-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and update the package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:somerville-dla-team/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Upgrading this package has been described at [No `dell-linux-assistant` program upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/1347991/159431). Since that question may not be considered a duplicate, I am posting the answer here as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I decided to adopt the advice and remove the Dell Linux Assistant application using:

```
sudo apt remove dell-recovery dell-linux-assistant
```

but I am going to request a new and better-adapted application from Dell.

I also checked with Dell support and according to them the Dell Linux Assistant application does not yet have support for Ubuntu 22.04.
Thanks for the help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

`isAlive` is a deprecated spelling of `is_alive`, used pre python3. It likely means you are running a script designed for Python 2, using Python 3.

This can easily happen in later versions of Ubuntu that don't have Python 2 installed. You've likely installed `python3-is-python`, such that the `python` command defaults to `python3`.

To solve it, you can either, in order of best-to-worse option:

1. Find a newer version of the failing script, compatible with `python3`.
2. install `python2` and make sure the script uses `python2`, by changing the shebang to be more explicit `python2` instead of `python`.
3. Install `python2-is-python` (This is very much NOT RECOMMENDED)

---

**References:**

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive

Comment: Well, I tried to install python2 with synaptic but the problem has not changed and I still get the same warning when rebooting the system.  Could you tell me in more detail what I should do?  Thank you

Comment: It's not clear how the script starts but appears to be something with DellLinuxAssistant. Find the main entrypoint of that program, in the first line it will probably say #!/usr/bin/env python. Change that line to #!/usr/bin/env python2.

Comment: I have found this archives but I dont know how to edit it