# Unable to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 LTS on Dell XPS 13 9310

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade Ubuntu from Terminal:

```
ada@dada-XPS-13-9310:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  dell-linux-assistant
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
dada@dada-XPS-13-9310:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
dada@dada-XPS-13-9310:~$
```

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1428487/edit) to show us the complete input and output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Please help with this:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No \`dell-linux-assistant\` program upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341276/no-dell-linux-assistant-program-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

First, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Edit the Update manager file to confirm that your system will get the LTS  version in the update:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Now run this command to upgrade:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Then follow the onscreen instructions to finish

Comment: The use of `-y` seems unwise when troubleshooting. You want to read the output before agreeing to the action.

Comment: The use of `-d` will have different results based upon the calendar. Using that flag today will cause a release-upgrade to fail.